# Use varchar or text for a dynamic field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I am building a table that will receive different values in a field, think of a log table that the "value" field can be a number, a tiny string or a big text etc.
So I was wonderig if I should create that "value" field as Text or create two fields, one for small inputs, like date, numbers and some string and another one only for the Texts inputs.

so, my question is this:
Should this "value" field be a Varchar along with some other "value2" as Text or create one field Text that the mysql will manage this corretcly?

I am afraid that creating only one Text field can be a bad thing for performance.

EDIT: the number, datetime etc are going to be cast as string before insertion, thats not the point

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Or maybe you just shoulldn't do something like that at all? What is the purpose of this table?

Comment: they are batch of commands. Users can create objects but they won't be saved untill approved by admin

Comment: and I must be able to show to other users that there are updates or insertions for those objects, so they won't create or update the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know how large the largest input will be? If you impose a limit, or know how large the maximum input will be, then you could use varchar (which caps at 255 characters in versions < 5.0.3, and 65,535 in versions >= 5.0.3). Otherwise, you're probably better off with Text, since it holds significantly more (65,535*2^16-1).

As an alternative, if users are creating things that already have tables (such as adding events to a calendar), you could just put an "is_approved" column on the table and only display approved ones, or search through everything to check for duplicates.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: TEXT is also capped at 2^16-1 = 65535B (bytes, not characters - careful about multibyte encodings). MEDUIMTEXT is 2^24-1 and LONGTEXT 2^32-1.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a limit to the length of that the data stored use [varchar()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) (as MySQL 5.0.3 varchar max length can be up to 65,535)

If there is no concrete limit then use a 'text' field type.

Comment: @Mchl, that is true, however if you know the upper limit (and it's less than 65,535) then using a varchar() is more efficient for working with the db.

Comment: So why are you suggesting TEXT for values longer than 64kB? ;) At least suggest [MEDIUM|LONG]TEXT. Also remember that MyISAM can only hold 64kB per row (BLOB/TEXT excluded) so you can't really have a full width varchar column in it.

Answer (score 0):

The varchar field can handle the different input's that you are mentioning but as a string, not as an integer or datetime.

Comment: yeah, stuff will be cast as string before being inserted in the field, but, they can be very tiny stuff like a boolean 0, -1 or a full text like a description of a product. My question is if I can have one field Text to handle this or should I create one varchar and one Text to handle them? or even specific, create one of each type, like int, float, datetime, varchar, text etc...

Comment: A single varchar field can hold all of these.